# How to get native notifications on chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, notification

I'm a newbie to ubuntu and I trying to get native notifications on chrome and I have tried Libnotify but not working.
Anyone, please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well it's already available nativly without installing any additional applications. If you have the latest **dev** channel of Google Chrome browser. If you don't want to install Dev channel then all you need to do is wait until it comes to Google Chrome stable.

**How to enable it in Chrome Dev?**

```
chrome://flags/#enable-native-notifications
```

Go to this URL and enable the flag by toggling it *Enabled*. And restart the browser.

And then notifications *should* technically work! It works as expected on Gnome but Unity seems to have a problem with it!

Can't complaint as its feature from Dev channel of Google Chrome.

[Download Chrome Dev](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/?platform=linux&extra=devchannel)

[Related Article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/chrome-native-linux-notifications-soon)